# Is there a way to manually add delay to all user input DOM events?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

For a research experiment I am trying to delay the user interface (create lag) on mobile browsers, as I am researching the effects of UI latency in webapps. For example, if a user scrolls the scroll action only happens (e.g.) 50ms later.

I've tried `window.addEventListener()`, and then `window.dispatchEvent()` after a certain delay with `setTimeout()`. Howver, in the case of scrolling, this did not scroll the page after dispatching the event manually. Scrolling with `window.scrollBy()` does work, but it fires its own event.

```
window.addEventListener('wheel', event => {
    console.log(event)
    if (event.cancelable) {
        event.preventDefault()
        event.stopImmediatePropagation()
        setTimeout(() => {
            let newEvent = new WheelEvent('wheel', {
                deltaX: event.deltaX,
                deltaY: event.deltaY,
                deltaZ: event.deltaZ,
                cancelable: false,
            })
            window.dispatchEvent(newEvent)
            // window.scrollBy({ top: 20 })
        }, DELAY)
    }
}, {
    capture: true,
    passive: false,
})
```

This works for wheel events, but not for touch events.
If there a way to generalize this behaviour for all MouseEvents?
Ideally I would like to process all DOM `MouseEvent`'s, like some sort of middleware.

Comment: is it necessary to voluntarily create a lag? Can't these create a false perception to your users to think that the app/phone is hanging/freezing?

Comment: (Unfortunately) this project is part of a thesis where the research scope is solely focused on the effects of UI latency and not hanging/freezing. As this is part of HFE studies hanging/freezing is considered to be a different experience we are not researching at this point.

Comment: I think what you want is debouncing?